# Custom Asp.net MVC 3 editor template not getting used

Tags: string, asp.net-mvc-3, html, razor, editortemplates

I have an MVC 3 web app that uses Razor view engine. I would like to extend default editor templates so I'd like to add additional HTML5 attributes to `input` elements like `autofocus`.

I'm using `AdditionalMetadataAttribute` to specify certain properties on my entity to be autofocus:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [AdditionalMetadata("autofocus", true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Since view scaffolding uses `EditorFor` method I decided to play along and wanted to override default **String.cshtml** template so that it would also add any additional metadata  as attributes. *To play along* means that I don't want to use `TextBoxFor` where I can control input's attributes.

This is my slightly changes **String.cshtml** that adds all additional metadata attributes as input HTML attributes:

```
@{
    // System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    this.ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.Add("class", "text-box single-line");
}
@Html.TextBox(string.Empty, ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, this.ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues)
```

This template should render the same `input type=text` with the same CSS classes but also with additional attributes if any of them are provided.

I then put this file in the **~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/** folder but it seems this template never gets picked up, because all I get is just the default input text box.

### What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just curious if there was a particular reason to use `[DataType(DataType.Text)]`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your `String.cshtml` editor template is never because of the following attribute: `[DataType(DataType.Text)]` that you used to decorate your model property with.

This uses the `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Text.cshtml` template.

Comment: Thanks Darin. I was just getting back to SO because I found out the same thing. Renaming it or removing that particular declarative attribute actually does make it work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: One more Q: I would like to consolidate two editor templates (**Text** and **String**) by not repeating code so I would like to reference one inside of the other (**Text** should just use **String**). I used `@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/String.cshtml")` but I get an error: *The partial view '~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/String.cshtml' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.*

Comment: Thanks mate... It was actually a typo yes... Because I have these templates only in one particular area. :) I obviously need some vacation. :) Thanks again.